# How do I unit test Rebus handlers IFailed<Message> handle when secondLevelRetriesEnabled is enabled

Tags: rebus

I am in the process of writing some unit tests for my Rebus Handlers. I have opted to enable `secondLevelRetriesEnabled` which results in an `IFailed<TMessage>` being published when an exception is thrown in the Handler.

My Handler class definition is:

```
Handler<T> : IHandleMessages<T>, IHandleMessages<IFailed<T>>
```

When I run the process everything works as expected; the difficulty comes when attempting to write a unit test for the `secondLevelRetriesEnabled` behaviour.

When my unit test calls the `IFailed<TMessage>` method of my Handler which results in a call to `await bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Deadletter(message)` I get the following exception from the `FakeBus`.

```
"Attempted to dead-letter the current message using error details 'Failed to handle message after 2 deferrals', but no message context could be found! This is probably a sign that this method was called OUTSIDE of a Rebus handler, or on a separate, disconnected thread somehow. Please only call this method inside Rebus handlers."
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to resolve the Deadletter queue exception when testing the IFailed message handle. As far as I can see there is no `HandleFixture` like the `SagaFixture` which supports `fixture.DeliverFailed(new OrdinaryMessage(...), new ApplicationException("oh no"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a really elegant way at the moment, but one way that you could wrap up and maybe make pretty yourself, is to do something like this:

```cs
// this is the message we're pretending to be handling
var transportMessage = new TransportMessage(...);

using var scope = new RebusTransactionScope();

var transactionContext = scope.TransactionContext;
var incomingStepContext = new IncomingStepContext(transportMessage, transactionContext);

// fake incoming step context here:
transactionContext.Items[StepContext.StepContextKey] = incomingStepContext;

// now MessageContext.Current should return a proper IMessageContext

//< exercise your handler here

//< check incomingStepContext here
```

This is clearly something that could be better, so feel free to raise an issue in the [Rebus.TestHelpers repository](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.TestHelpers), which would be the right place to live for some kind of solution to this problem.